# SQL: divide int by number of transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to divide the TWin by the # of transactions over a time period.
Example: if customer has TWin of 100 and came in 5 days between Jan 1 & May 1 = 20.
Please Help. Thank You.

```
select PlayerID, CashIn, **TWin/SUM(GamingDate)** as Daily_Theo, PtsEarned
from CDS_StatDay
where GamingDate between '1/1/2017' and '5/1/2017'
group by PlayerID, CashIn, TWin, PtsEarned
order by CDS_StatDay.PlayerID asc
```

Comment: You don't want to SUM your date column, you want to COUNT it.

Comment: What are the datatypes of CashIn, TWin, and PtsEarned? Could they be different between rows for the same PlayerId? That will interfere with your sum being correct per PlayerId.

Comment: Thank You Pablo, any insight into solving this simple equation?

Comment: all data types are int...basically i am getting each individual days stats but need to divide them by count of transactions over time period

Comment: Again....don't sum the GamingDate column. How can you sum a date, let alone divide by the sum of a date??? Your grouping is also a little questionable.

Comment: Thank You Sean, I solved it...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right what you want to do try something like this

```
select v.PlayerID, v.CashIn, v.TWin, v.PtsEarned,
       case cnt when 0 then 0 else v.TWin / v.cnt end as Daily_Theo
from (
select PlayerID, CashIn, TWin, count(GamingDate) over (partition by PlayerID) as cnt,
   PtsEarned
from CDS_StatDay
where GamingDate between '1/1/2017' and '5/1/2017'
) v
order by v.PLayerID
```